# Create a generic type that, given a field's key, types a subfield of that entry with the type of one of its fields

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings, typescript-generics

I have this object

```
const test = {
  thing1: {
    name: "one",
    fields: {
      thing1Field1: {
        default: "text",
      },
      thing1Field2: {
        default: 13,
      },
    },
  },
  thing2: {
    name: "two",
    fields: {
      thing2Field1: {
        default: 12,
      },
    },
  },
};
```

I'm trying to write a generic type that takes in `"thing1" | "thing2"` and gives back types for each of its `fields.default`s.

Desired output would be:

```
// ThingType<"thing1"> ->
// {
//   thing1Field1: string;
//   thing1Field2: number;
// }

// ThingType<"thing2"> ->
// {
//   thing2Field1: number;
// }
```

I tried this:

```
type ThingType<T extends keyof typeof test> = {
  [fieldName in keyof typeof test[T]["fields"]]: typeof test[T]["fields"][fieldName]["default"];
};
```

but "default" can't index into `typeof test[T]["fields"]`.
[image]

Is it possible to derive such a type from the object without explicit type definitions on `test`? (If not, how would you type `test` to allow this?)

Comment: This is a known TS bug, see [ms/TS#21760](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/21760); workarounds would be [as shown here](https://tsplay.dev/WPzJzN).  Does that fully address your question? If so I'll write up an answer; if not, what am I missing?

Comment: Yes, thank you, I tried your first workaround and it resolved the error. I just assumed my approach wouldn't enforce the correct types because of the error :/

Comment: Okay I'll write up an answer when I get a chance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a known bug in TypeScript; see [microsoft/TypeScript#21760](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/21760); the [constraint](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html#generic-constraints) for the second [generic](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html) type parameter is, erroneously, widened all the way to something like `string`:

```
type ThingType<K extends keyof Test> = { [P in keyof Test[K]["fields"]]:
    Test[K]["fields"][P]["default"] // error! "default" cannot index...
}
```

*We* know that `Test[K]["fields"][P]` must have a `"default"` key, but the compiler has forgotten this because `P` has been widened.  This bug has been around for a very long time and is not slated to be fixed in any upcoming version of the language.  So we might be stuck with this for the foreseeable future.

---

Luckily, you can work around it in a few ways.  If there is a type `X` that you know is assignable to another type `Y`, but the compiler does *not* know this, then you can replace `X` with `Extract<X, Y>` using [the `Extract<X, Y>` utility type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#extracttype-union).  This is an off-label use of `Extract`, which is primarily intended to filter unions... but if `X` is assignable to `Y`, then `Extract<X, Y>` will eventually resolve to just `X`; the difference is that the compiler recognizes `Extract<X, Y>` as also assignable to `Y`.  So you can write `ThingType` like this:

```
type ThingType<K extends keyof Test> = { [P in keyof Test[K]["fields"]]:
    Extract<Test[K]["fields"][P], { default: any }>["default"] // okay
}
```

where `Extract<Test[K]["fields"][P], {default: any}>` will resolve to `Test[K]["fields"][P]` later, but now the compiler sees it as definitely containing a `default` property.

---

Another workaround is to use [conditional type inference](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/conditional-types.html#inferring-within-conditional-types) instead of [indexed access](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/indexed-access-types.html):

```
type ThingType<K extends keyof Test> = {
    [P in keyof Test[K]["fields"]]:
    Test[K]["fields"][P] extends { default: infer D } ? D : never;
}
```

where we `infer` the `default` property to its own type parameter `D`.

---

Both workarounds suppress the error and result in the desired outputs:

```
type T1 = ThingType<"thing1">
/* type T1 = {
    thing1Field1: string;
    thing1Field2: number;
} */
type T2 = ThingType<"thing2">
/* type T2 = {
    thing2Field1: number;
} */
```

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.9.4#code/MYewdgzgLgBFCm0YF4YG8BQNtwBYEswBzARgC50sdqwBDAW3goCJx5mAaK67AM33gAbACYQKmHpLyFSAMQEjylKSpjD4vWgFdBUFggAeUTt1UBfLqpxQCxEvKHCATONNXs6zTr0wSAZkt3CzccYOow61siF2UpOkZ9AHcQExV+RzFYqxsZJwdFV3ceT21dChInQKsIyRqYYLMAbgwMKABPAAd4GAAVRFhUdq6QXjh+5ox4xA7aYG6AORAurLhO7p6onrWAHgBpGHgjeDBRGABreDaR3v6APhR0GABtAAUYQnPL677oJ92AXSezHSIggzH+-zIIWwPygf0BwIUonBrwRJW84JgAHosQcAE54kB4gCEMBa4QwZhakwY01m3QA6kSzrRCVoTgBRIx42awCTWNa9TY7faHBAnCCfK6jWH3VBoZ5vD4XaU3X4AoEg5EQqEqLlQHnAKDbWHwzVIsGAl7-DiPdFlGC0MBteq3IH24z-UxU6hDdYkB4bGRbLrbZg5OzMW6mLEAKlWyx6Afl0OkdnywiU0DxMmaKgjciRMTAWnoACN4Hi86EYLGsaY-b0nIHhaHw1EnFGY-HGz1myn8x2M0oS+XK9XsGZa-XKS0phAZnMYEy8Sy2ScAJJgXiVla91vwPYHI4SqXfO4PfmSV7vMBnmX9M2IjLgyGp00a5+glHW4-i04Kh6FCEDueIwAAIvUMAAPwQTAFBgPAABu47eg2gpJi2wY7O2MgkF21Bxgm-qXqmBb2EiWYGrmZFRBRjjFqWFZVt607oYm-ZCthbYFp20aET2GGcVePC8cOCFMah4RsbOQA)